# Highlighting child item in QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to select child item in QTreeView after clearing widget model(QStandardItemModel)? In need clearing to update data in view and highlight last selected item. I can select parent item, but not child.

Selecting parent is like that

[image]

Highlighting child didnt work. Parent Group 1 selected instead of Server 1. How to select Server 1?
[image]

```
  flag = None
  index = self.treeView.currentIndex()
  # If selected parent
  if not index.parent().isValid():
    col_parent = 0    
    row_parent = index.row()
    flag = True
            
  # if child
  elif index.parent().isValid():
    child_index = self.treeModel.index(0,0,index.parent())
    flag = False

  self.treeModel.clear()
  self.showDataInTree()  # My method to fill QTreeView 

  # Highlight last item
  if flag:
    self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(
      self.treeModel.index(row_parent,col_parent))
  elif not flag:
    self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(child_index)
```

Comment: If you clear the model, any previous index becomes invalid. Instead of completely clearing the model, you should probably reuse existing items/parents so that at least the parent index will be valid and you can easily access its children.

Comment: @musicamante, I create  vatiable index = self.treeView.currentIndex() before to clear model.

Comment: As already said, any previously created index becomes invalid for the model when you clear it. QModelIndex uses internal pointers to store references in the model, if the model is cleared, the references to those pointers are not valid anymore. The fact that the item has the same name or position in the model is completely irrelevant. If you are certain that the structure will be preserved, then you could reconstruct the index programmatically by creating the *new* indexes based on the position in the tree structure, and that's the only option you have if you clear the model.

Comment: @musicamante, I understand now. But what's the other way to refresh qtreeview and save last selection item?

Comment: I suggested that earlier: instead of clearing the model, populate it by trying to reuse existing items. I don't know how you populate the model, so but assuming that some of those parent "folders" are always present, you should eventually clear their content and add new children to them. In this way, the parent item (and its related index) will be persistent. Note that a more appropriate way to store a persistent index after altering the model is by using QPersistentModelIndex. If you want more help, please provide a valid [mre] that shows how the model is populated.